# How to load multiple sheets of an Excel File in SSIS with header information in the sheets

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I have a file with 2 sheets in it. It has the header information in it. I tried foreach loop container to load the data 
Error i got is:
[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: "Excel Source" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA".

I tried removing the header row manually from the sheets and ran foreach loop container and it worked perfectly fine.

But in my requirement i will be getting the header row followed by blank row in each sheet.
How do i do in this case.
I believe we need to use script task to to eliminate header and followed null row from the file and read the rest of the records.

My problem is i am bad at c# code logic.

Your help is much appreciated.
Thank you,
swathi

Answer (score 0):

The following Script Task will delete the top 2 rows from every worksheet in the file (you'll need to create the variable 'ExcelFilePath' in SSIS and pass that in to the task, along with 'System::TaskName'):

```
public void Main()
{
    MainTask();

    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
}

private void MainTask()
{
    xl.Application xlApp = null;
    xl.Workbook excelFile = null;
    string excelFilePath = Dts.Variables["User::ExcelFilePath"].Value.ToString();
    string thisTask = Dts.Variables["System::TaskName"].Value.ToString();

    try
    {
        xlApp = new xl.Application();

        excelFile = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(excelFilePath);

        xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;

        foreach (xl.Worksheet ws in excelFile.Worksheets)
        {
            ws.Rows["1:2"].EntireRow.Delete();
        }

        xlApp.DisplayAlerts = true;

        excelFile.Save();
        excelFile.Close();

        xlApp.Quit();

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Dts.Events.FireError(0, thisTask, ex.Message, String.Empty, 0);

        if (excelFile != null) excelFile.Close(SaveChanges:false);
        if (xlApp != null) xlApp.Quit();
    }
}
```

You will need to add references to 'COM' > 'Microsoft Excel [version number] Object Library' (whichever version you have) and '.NET' > 'Microsoft.CSharp'. You'll then need to declare `using xl = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;` in your 'Namespaces' region.